# Paths in PHP, which is correct -- absolute or relative?

Tags: php

In my code, I have included some files for use. When I specify the absolute path, I get a "Forbidden" message.

However, when I use the relative path, the code works.

I wonder why the absolute path was not being accepted.

Can someone explain what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no general difference between absolute and relative paths: They all get resolved internally. Please show some code to tell what's going on.

Comment: Post your code... without looking at it its hard to understand your specific problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save yourself from trouble, always use absolute one.
As for your case, it's easy. You're just using a wrong path. Most likely you messed up a **web root** with **filesystem root.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a shared host, they can restrict you not to reach other than your content, so absolute paths can cause troubles.

Comment: Not really: Absolute paths are fine as long as they are inside the allowed path(s).

Comment: In some security configurations this is not allowed. 

That said, some applications do really silly stuff like 
    `/var/www/appdir$ cd ../appdir/foo`

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the account under which PHP runs doesn't have access to some portion of the absolute path.

E.g. if your absolute path is /home/user/site/pages and the account doesn't have access to '/home/user', you would see this.